# Why doesn't available space increase if I grow my virtual hard drive?

Tags: partitioning

I have increased my Ubuntu's hard disk size to 40GB. But still I don't see it's increased!

I increased it through *VM → Settings → Hard Disk(SCSI) → Utilities → Expand*. When I power on and and see in terminal, it shows only 7.7GB Free. I want to install some more size DB servers. Due to this, I am unable to do anything on it.

Comment: You need to resize the partitions too, not just the virtual disk.

Comment: How to do that? Provide me the steps Please. Thank You.

Comment: If anyone done it Or related post link would also help me!!

Comment: The process is the same as highlighted in the duplicate except that instead of rebooting the host computer to a LiveCD, you're rebooting the virtual machine to a LiveCD. *Exactly* how you do that will differ from VM to VM but it's essentially the same as the method you followed to install until you get to the Try Ubuntu choice.

Comment: I have Partitioned But still if i right click on desktop i could see only 5.5GB free. Below are my partition details.

Comment: root@ubuntu:~# fdisk -l /dev/sda
Disk /dev/sda: 42.9 GB, 42949672960 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 5221 cylinders, total 83886080 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x000c1d66

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048    37748735    18873344   83  Linux
/dev/sda2        37750782    41940991     2095105    5  Extended

Comment: Some one from forum(ubuntu) suggested to go for latest version for well user friendly. So, i have started with 12.04.3 server ...Thanks.